# firestore rules simulator fails - Possible boolean short-circuiting issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console, firebase-security

**Problem**:  Firestore rule simulator gives me a red failure banner at the top when I attempt to create an object in the `a` collection.

Here's the banner:

[image]

Simulator inputs:

- Type:  `create`
- Path:  `/z/zid0/a/aid0`
- I setup some doc content
- Authenticated:  `check`
- Provider: `google`
- AuthId: `aid0`
- Email Verified: `yes`

Here is an abbreviated rule source:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {

        match /z/{zId} {
          function isWriteAllowedCurrentZ() {
              return getUserDataForCurrentZ().keys().hasAll(['write'])
          }

          function getUserDataForCurrentZ() {
              return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/z/$(zId)/a/$(request.auth.uid)).data;
          }

          function zExists() {
              return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/z/$(zId))
          }

          function isCreateA_Allowed() {
              return !zExists() || isWriteAllowedCurrentZ()
          }

          match /a/{document=**} {
              allow create: if isCreateA_Allowed();
          }
    }
}
```

**Expectation**
Because zid0 does not exist, I'm expecting the create of `/z/zid0/a/aid0` to succeed because `isCreateA_Allowed()` -> `!zExists()` will return true.

**Result**
Above red banner appears.

**Current Throughts**
I suspect the firestore rule evaluator is not short-circuiting the boolean logic.  It ends up calling `IsWriteAllowedCurrentZ()` even though `!zExists()` is true and OR'd with it.  `IsWriteAllowedCurrentZ()` will attempt to access a non-existent object and fails (not returns false, but fails) and this bubbles out of the simulator as a false.  I've been able to simulate valid denials, and similar to the succeeds, I get a red 'x' mark next to the rule making the making the decision.  This is a much different visual compared to the red banner seen above.

**Things Tried**

- Tried making `isCreateA_Allowed` only check !zExists().  This works (I get a green check mark)

  ```
  function isCreateA_Allowed() {
      return !zExists() // || isWriteAllowedCurrentZ()
  }
  ```
- Tried changing isWriteAllowedCurrentZ to always return false.  This works (I get a green check mark)

  ```
    function isWriteAllowedCurrentZ() {
        return false // getUserPermsDataForCurrentZ().keys().hasAll(['write'])
    }
  ```
- Tried doing an exists check before calling getUserDataForCurrentZ(), this does NOT work.  It generates the same red banner.

  ```
    function isWriteAllowedCurrentZ() {
        return doesUserDataExist() && getUserDataForCurrentZ().keys().hasAll(['write'])
    }
  ```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!